# Xcode autocompletion of import statement not working (cocoapods)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I just created a blank project and using cocoapods I added to dependancies.
AFNetworking & BlockRSSParser.
I ran the cocoapods command to configure my workspace and opened is.
Everything looks great. I can use both AFNetworking & BlockRSSParser code.

But one little thing is bugging me. The #import statement for classes in the Pods do not autocomplete. I have to type them out manually. They do validate though.

- Pods.xcconfig is being used.
- I am not overriding HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS.
- If I look in the searchpaths, I can see the header files there.
- The import statements I write without autocompletion are valid.
- Code dependent on the import statements is valid & functional.

How do I get autocomplete on the import statements working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use <> instead of  "" for importing cocoapod libraries

Comment: Do you know if CocoaPods can support the new "@import module" syntax in XCode 5? Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: According to the 2013 WWDC presentation on the topic of new Xcode features (or new obj-c features, memory fuzzy) the @import feature works only with Apple frameworks at the moment.